# Value in "word" makes no difference to my if statement

Tags: python

I am on day 4 of learning python so I apologize in advance if I am missing something very obvious.

The entire program is posted below. `word = input()` no matter what I type into the input prompt my tree function will not be called. However if I change: `if word == 'Chris' or 'j':` to `if word == 'Chris':` it seems to work.

```
def tree(pine):
    return 'Hello' + pine


def app():
    word = input()
    if word == 'Chris' or 'j':
        print('Welcome ' + word + ' it is nice today! ', end='')
        print('It is so sunny')
    else:
        print(tree('lplp'))



app()
```

Comment: Like this:  ```if word == 'Chris' or word ==  'j':```

Comment: You may want to format your string too:  print(f'Welcome {word} it is nice today!')

Comment: `if word in {'Chris', 'j'}:`

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure on this, but the reason your code is always true is because when you perform `if variable_name:` statements, you're asking Python if said variable is not None nor False. In this case the string 'j' is always not-None non-False, so your statement will always evaluate to True, and thus the `else` statement will never run

Comment: @JuanC not exactly, every data type has its own python `bool` quirk. in the case of strings, any non empty string is evaluated as `True`

Comment: Nice! I'm clearer now

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with

```py
    if word == 'Chris' or 'j':
```

If we break down this statement, you're evaluating two conditions:

1. `word == 'Chris'`
2. `'j'`

So Python is a funny language because pretty much any kind of object can be evaluated as a boolean. This means when you check `if 'j'`, that actually comes out as `True` instead of some sort of error because Python does a lot of stuff behind the scenes.

To fix the issue you just want to make sure you're checking that `word == "j"`.

Just to get you started, for example, here are some common python boolean evals:

```py
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool("j")
True
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool(69)
True
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool(["hello", "world"])
True
>>> class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "y"


>>> bool(Foo())
True
>>> bool(None)
False
```